# Looking for an easy way to cluster well separated 2D data in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have 2D data with x and y positions for up to one millions cells. I would like to autamatically annotate the cells to different locations.
In the example below, I expect to find 4 clusters corresponding the 4 ellipses.
So far I tried kmeans and GMM but failed to correctly assing the cells to the expected clusters.
HDBSCAN was able to do so on a subset of the cells but is limited by RAM on the whole dataset.
Is there any other R tool that would be suited for this use case?
Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lookup the `stream` package for R. It is designed to perform analysis on a datastream instead of a fixed dataset, therefore it can handle limited RAM resources. Within `stream`, you can use the birch algorithm if you do not know the amount of clusters. But there are also streaming versions of other cluster algorithms available.